# Image url Listview Xamarin

Tags: url, xamarin, imageview

Code to download images and view in imageview

```
public override View GetView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
    {
        var feedItem = this.feedsList[position];

        var view = (convertView ?? context.LayoutInflater.Inflate(Resource.Layout.ItemListItemLayout, parent, false)) as LinearLayout;

        var img = view.FindViewById<ImageView>(Resource.Id.imazhi);
        var imageBitmap2 = GetImageBitmapFromUrl(feedItem.link_img);
        img.SetImageBitmap(imageBitmap2);

        return view;
    }

 private Bitmap GetImageBitmapFromUrl(string url)
    {
        Bitmap imageBitmap = null;

        using (var webClient = new WebClient())
        {
            try
            {
                var imageBytes = webClient.DownloadData(url);
                if (imageBytes != null && imageBytes.Length > 0)
                {

                    imageBitmap = BitmapFactory.DecodeByteArray(imageBytes, 0, imageBytes.Length);
                }
            }
            catch
            {

            }
        }

        return imageBitmap;
    }
```

It works but it takes times to load and I can not move on the phone screen
. Are more than forty images

What I want :

Load more without crashing my screen

While it loads I can move the listview

Example of applications with images: Instagram, facebook where the photos are loaded does not lock the screen

Can someone help me ? sorry the English ; )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I use `FFImageLoading` in my Xamarin.Android app and it works very well. It automatically caches images to disk and offers many more features.

nuget: https://www.nuget.org/packages/Xamarin.FFImageLoading/

Documentation: https://github.com/luberda-molinet/FFImageLoading/wiki

Use ImageViewAsync instead of ImageView

```
<FFImageLoading.Views.ImageViewAsync
    android:id="@+id/imgLiterature"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:adjustViewBounds="true"
    android:background="@android:drawable/ic_menu_gallery"
    android:scaleType="fitXY" />
```

and to load image:

```
public void LoadImage (FFImageLoading.Views.ImageViewAsync imageview, string url)
{
    ImageService.Instance.Initialize (new Configuration {
                    HttpClient = new HttpClient() // here you can add authentication if needed
    });
    ImageService.Instance.LoadUrl (url).Into (imageview);
}
```

it runs asynchronously and doesn't block the ui